# Regex for external links: how to make an exception for my own link?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am using `regex` to change plain text to url if there is `http://` before the text. This works fine, but I don't want to make them a link if this link is `internal` (so a link that contains my websites name)... **So I only want it to happen if it is an external link.**

How can I do that? I tried adding a `!` before the http, but it did not work. Can someone help me out please? This is what I am using:

```
function wpse107488_urls_to_links( $string ) {

   $string = preg_replace( "/([^\w\/])(www\.[a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z0-9\-]+)/i", "$1http://$2", $string );

    $string = preg_replace( "/([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;%#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i", "<a target=\"_blank\" title=\"" . __( 'Visit Site', 'your-textdomain' ) . "\" href=\"$1\">$1</a>", $string);

    return $string;
}
```

*Edit: I am using a different function that makes a link from my internal links too (that is supposed to be so), but I think these two functions are blocking each other. That's why I gave a class to all my internal links. Can I exclude them using these classes?*

Comment: you can try all sorta of different techniques. Here is a nice link that illustrates these with jQuery http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/target-only-external-links/ , seems like you are intereted in technique #3

Comment: Thanks, but it's a Wordpress site and I am using PHP, not jQuery.

Comment: WordPress uses jQuery and PHP, so I don't know what you mean by "not using" jQuery

Comment: Sorry, I know, but I meant that it is not a function that I can put it in `functions.php` and use it directly.

Comment: Ok, if you give up on that `functions.php` way of doing it, there's some nice jQuery out there that will handle this the exact same way with Regex. All the best, I'll check back here to see if you found a way to do it with pure PHP (which I am also sure is very possible)

Comment: Thanks sulfureous, I will give that one a try too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the following:

`/((http|https):\/\/(?!www.google.co.uk)[\w\.\/\-=?#]+)/` for *http* and *https*

**OR**

`/(http:\/\/(?!www.google.co.uk)[\w\.\/\-=?#]+)/` fot *http* only

You can then replace `www.google.co.uk` with your domain name (in the format that it is shown on your site).

Used on the following it will match all URLs except for `http://www.google.co.uk`...

```
A few websites to test the regex http://www.google.co.uk http://www.myspace.com http://facebook.com http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=video32 it should have matched all but the google URL.
```

The above regex will also match youtube videos etc. with `GET` strings attached and internal links (i.e. `#`)

**Update**

The following regex will replace all external links starting either `http://` or `www` with an anchor tag to the URL opening in a new window/tab.

```
$string = preg_replace( "/((http:\/\/|www)(?!mydomain\.com)[\w\.\/\-=?#]+)/", "<a target='_blank\' href='$1'>$1</a>", $string);
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of your links and an external link?

Comment: Well, my link is `http://mydomain.com` and external can be `http://externalink.com` or `http:// www.externalink.com`

Comment: See my edit. I added classes to my internal links. Can I use that to distinguish them?

Comment: Okay, in that case I'm not sure what you mean? You said that the function was working on plain text? Plain text cannot have classes or mark up, otherwise it isn't plain text?! Perhaps you could copy/paste your other function as well as the plain text that both are working on.

Comment: Well, with plain text I mean an anchor that isn't a link actually, but that has a class. Sorry for putting it that way, I thought to simple... The problem with this function is that I still can't exclude websites. It is still affecting my own links.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34137/discussion-between-steven-and-johan)

Comment: Steven, thanks for your help, but I need you very quickly for something else (related question). Can you come to chat, please? It is about Youtube, which is no more embedding video's since I implemented your solution.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't around earlier when you sent this... But I have since been back to chat and explained a fix! (at least a fix for what I assumed the problem was)

Comment: /https?/ will match both, "http" and "https"

Answer (score 0):

You can add a negative lookahead `(?!..)` *(not followed by)* with your domain name, an example in a super general pattern* to detect urls:

```
$string = preg_replace('~\bhttps?://(?:www\.)?(?!mydomain.com)[^\s/]+(?:/[^\s/]+)*/?~i',
                       '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $string );
```

** that means that i didn't spent time to an url pattern, if you find a better pattern, change it. It is only to illustrate how to exclude your domain.*

Comment: don't forget the possibility of a https-link ;)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. Same problem exists... Maybe it's because I don't use www but http://mydomain.com instead? Why wouldn't this work?

Comment: the answer is a good hint, what you have to do. please read the manual of regexp to know what you have to change...

Comment: I know what I have to change, that's not the problem. The problem is that it still gets my internal links!

Comment: @MichaelWalter See my edit. I added classes to my internal links. Can I use that to distinguish them?