# Regex to Select a Sub-Set of a Regex Select

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I haven't had any luck searching on this and I believe that's because I don't know the key terms to use to explain what I'm looking for. I have the following regex that I'm using to distinguish internal links on a set of HTML pages from external links:

```
(?<=a href=")[^http](.*?)(\.html")
```

So it won't select "http://www.example.com/foo/bar.html" from:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/foo/bar.html">bar</a>
```

but will select "/foo/bar.html" from:

```
<a href="/foo/bar.html">bar</a>
```

This much is working great. Now I want to do a subselect on the selected string "/foo/bar.html" to isolate just the ".html" part. Is this possible? Possibly with a substring or another lookbehind/forward? I've setup an example here:

https://www.regex101.com/r/gZ6bP5/2

This is for a global find/replace in Sublime Text Editor. So I believe I am restricted to just the regex for this. I understand that a variable find/replace is possible, but I have not been able to find an example of that in action.

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, the regex I have to distinguish between external/internal links works great (although imperfectly as commenters have noted). The question is about how to select just the ".html" portion of the match.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to the link you have posted, the `.html` part is already made available to you through the second group. I am not a sublime user but you should be able to access it through something like `/2`, `$2` or `${2}`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for external links: how to make an exception for my own link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836053/regex-for-external-links-how-to-make-an-exception-for-my-own-link)

Comment: Technically your existing pattern doesn't work the way you described.  For instance, it won't match `a href="hello.html"`, since it starts with an `h`.  `[^http]` defines a character class, so it only matches a single character.  To exclude matches for the whole string, you need a negative look-ahead (e.g. `(?<=a href=")(?!http)(.*?)(\.html")`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
(?<=a href=")(?!http)[^"]*\/([^"]+)(?=">)
```

The idea:

- Use look-behind `(?<=a href=")` to ensure we are in a link anchor.
- Use look-ahead `(?=">)` to ensure the anchor ends.
- Use negative look-ahead `(?!http)` to ensure things don't start with http.
- Use a greed match `[^"]*` to capture all characters up to the last slash, without crossing a quote-boundary.
- Grab all characters after the last slash but before the quote boundary in a capture group `([^"]+)`

Problems you may encounter:

- This is valid HTML `<a target="_blank" href="bob.html">`.
- This is a valid link `<a href="ftp://bob.html">`.

Though you can build regexes to deal with these as well.

To deal with the target issue, we drop the look-behind, and the final look-ahead:

```
<a[^>]*href="(?!http)[^"]*\/([^"]+)
```

Now we are matching a string that starts with `<a` and looking for a `href="` inside of it. By dropping `(?=">)`, we are able to handle anchors with many tags.

To deal with `ftp`, we could do the following:

```
<a[^>]*href="(?!(http|ftp))[^"]*\/([^"]+)
```

Now, you can wrap the beginning of the string in a capture group:

```
(<a[^>]*href="(?!(http|ftp))[^"]*\/)([^"]+)
```

And alter `$1` (the part up to FILENAME.EXTENION) and `$2` (the FILENAME.EXTENSION) as you see fit.

An example is at: https://www.regex101.com/r/gZ6bP5/3.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for such a thorough answer. I saw the variables $1 and $2 in other posts, but did not understand them. Working through this excellent break-down of what's going on made it all click. I put $1 in the "replace" field and that keeps just what I wanted. The only edit I would make to your answer is that your regex example is selecting the whole filename and not just the file extension.

Comment: Thanks, @ideonexus! Now that I reread your question, I see that you are just looking for the extension. My apologies. Presumably you've figured out how to isolate this now?

Comment: I did! I added a second capture set (I now know what that is thanks to you) so: `(<a[^>]*href="(?!(http|ftp))[^"]*\/)([^\.]+)([^"]+)` and then then in the replace field I set it to $1$2 to keep everything but the ".html" part. It works great! Thanks again! This really worked wonders to demystifying regex for me.

Comment: My pleasure. Note that using `([^\.]+)` might get you into trouble if the filename has multiple periods in it and you want the last one, in which case you could use `(.+\.)([^"]+)`. The plus operator will capture one more characters before the period and greedily consume to the last period.